# Хіба Г це [h/ɦ], а не [ɣ]?

Tags: фонетика

Дискутував я недавно про транслітерацію іноземних назв українською, Геґрід тощо. Листування дійшло до того, чи справді англійське та не тільки H це українське Г, а не Х. Я подумав, що зазвичай про різницю г-х і де тут h не міркую, завжди більше акцент на г-ґ=h-g. Тому вирішив почитати про звуки й довірився трьом різномовним версіям Вікіпедії.

З прочитаного випливає :

- Х [`x`, глухий велярний фрикативний] є в укр і рос, в англ нема (є в діалектах, на деяких місцях). На звукових прикладах особисто мені здається, що це таке "повнозвучне" Х
- Г [`ɦ`, дзвінкий гортанний фрикативний] є в укр, в англ в RP; H в англ це зазвичай [`h`, глухий гортанний фрикативний], також пишуть що і іноді українське г таке. Але мені на слух ці звуки не здаються нашим Г, радше якісь "недовидихи", ще й обидва радше Х, ніж Г
- [`ɣ`, дзвінкий велярний фрикативний] (дзвінкий для [x]) мені на звук здається "нормальним" та "повнозвучним" Г; пишуть що це або білоруське г, або російське діалектне південне і в ага, господи..., про укр тільки кажуть що це варіант для Х

Тобто, г-х в українській це не точна пара "дзвінкий-глухий" (в "Українська фонетика" пишуть, що все одно пара, але стоїть [джерело?]) та Г має вимовлятися не зовсім так, як я собі уявляв (як порівняти до Х).

Це справді так? Г-Х справді не зовсім в парі, і Г має бути гортанним, а не велярним? Для мене це трохи дивно, зважаючи на мій досвід української школи та українського мовного оточення. Але я також серйозно не вчив фонетики, тому можливо не відрізняю чи не маю гарних джерел. Що скажете?

Comment: а в нас хіба ще немає такого питання?

Comment: @P.Vowk, про передачу іншомовних G і H — безліч. Але про те, що винесено в назву («Хіба Г це [h/ɦ], а не [ɣ]?») — здається, ні (точніше, є [одне англійською](/q/1137), але, здається, ми вирішили не вважати англ. і укр. сторінки дублікатами).

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Відразу зазначу, що я не спеціаліст, просто намагаюся підсумувати те, що колись читав…</sub>

#### Вимова українського Г

Наскільки я знаю, [немає повної згоди](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ukrainian_phonology&oldid=1000870671):

- дехто вважає, що це [дзвінкий гортанний фрикативний [ɦ]](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (зокрема: Stefan Pugh, Ian Press «Ukrainian: A Comprehensive Grammar», 2005 на с. 23; [«Український правопис», 2015 на с. 19](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par14); [українська Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%93&oldid=27756467) наразі висвітлює лише цю версію, хоча це, звісно, не аргумент);
- дехто вважає, що це [дзвінкий глотковий фрикативний [ʕ]](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (зокрема Andrii Danyenko, Serhii Vakulenko «Ukrainian», 1995 на с. 12; [«Український правопис», 2019 на с. 12](https://www.ulif.org.ua/system/files/pravopus-new.pdf#page=12)).

Є ще один схожий звук — [дзвінкий велярний/задньопіднебінний/задньоязиковий/м'якопіднебінний фрикативний [ɣ]](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), але його вважають білоруською вимовою Г, а не українською.

Коли я намагаюся прослухати зразки [гортанного [ɦ]][ɦ], [глоткового [ʕ]][ʕ] і [велярного [ɣ]][ɣ] у Вікісховищі (на Вікіпедії), мені особисто здається найбільш схожим на українську останній (тобто саме той, про який усі мовознавці стверджують, що це не українська вимова). Я маю два припущення для пояснення:

- можливо, ці терміни («гортанний», «глотковий» і «велярний») і значки («ɦ», «ʕ» і «ɣ») не мають на меті точно описати звук, а описують лише природу його утворення, тобто одним значком іноді можуть описуватися доволі різні для українського вуха звуки;
- можливо, просто на Вікісховищі не найвдаліші записи (наприклад, гортанний [ɦ] на YouTube-каналі «Ubc VISIBLE SPEECH» уже здається мені значно подібнішим до Г).

|  | гортанний [ɦ] | глотковий [ʕ] | велярний [ɣ] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Вікісховище | [▶](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Voiced_glottal_fricative.ogg) | [▶](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Voiced_pharyngeal_fricative.ogg) | [▶](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Voiced_velar_fricative.ogg) |
| Ubc VISIBLE SPEECH | [▶](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d5MoI0Malw) | [▶](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QR5mnivG6k) | [▶](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xz9Q38rmXi0) |
| Glossika Phonics |  | [▶](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3057MbWmH1k) | [▶](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmGjJNGTuIs) |

#### Пара українському Г

Якщо вірити вищенаведеному твердженню (що український Г — це гортанний [ɦ] або глотковий [ʕ], але не велярний [ɣ]), то українські Г і Х не утворюють точної фонетичної пари:

|  | Дзвінкий | Глухий |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Гортанний | [ɦ] <sub>український Г за твердженням деяких мовознавців</sub> | [h] <sub>англійський H у деяких мовців</sub> |
| Глотковий | [ʕ] <sub>український Г за твердженням деяких мовознавців</sub> | [ħ] <sub>англійський H у деяких мовців</sub> |
| Велярний | [ɣ] <sub>білоруський Г</sub> | [x] <sub>український і білоруський X</sub> |

Але в межах шкільної програми Г і Х таки називають парою. Я припускаю, через те що:

- точної фонетичної пари однаково немає, а це найближчі відповідники;
- саме таким чином відбувається чергування (Х — Ш — С; Г — Ж — З; К — Ч — Ц; Ґ — (Д)Ж — (Д)З).

<sub>Тему передання іншомовних G і H в українській не розкриваю.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Це добре, що люди ставлять подібні запитання і замислюються. Але слід звертатися до надійних джерел наукової інформації.

Наприклад, є наукові публікації, в яких містяться результати досліджень автора цієї відповіді, який, зокрема, брав участь у міжнародному фонетичному проєкті Lionbridge:

- [Calculation of phonetic distances between speech sounds](https://www.academia.edu/40718800);
- [Ukrainian Consonant Phones in the IPA Context with Special Reference to /v/ and /gh/. In: Linguistica online 22: 36-61](https://www.academia.edu/40178358).

Зокрема, укр. фонема /г/ позначається грецькою гамою.  У неї є алофони. Які саме — точно невідомо, оскільки немає достатніх фонетичних даних. Можливо, це фарингальний (або гортанний) і задньоязиковий.

На цю тему вже було обговорення за участю фахівців із фонетики, перекладу та історії мови. Можна переглянути тут:

- [обговорення «Щодо наукової неспроможності „г-концепції“», ініційоване автором цієї відповіді на форумі R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8387);
- [допис «Останні новини про „г-концепцію“. Серпень 2020» у блозі автора цієї відповіді](https://site.ua/maxvakul/30612-ostanni-novini-pro-g-kontseptsiyu-serpen-2020/).

Comment: **Дякую за доповнення до Вашої відповіді!** Я взяв на себе сміливість трішки відредагувати її, (1) **прибравши критику вікіпедії**; (2) **чистіше оформивши посилання**. Критика вікіпедії здається мені надмірною: хоча сама вікіпедія, звісно, не є науковим чи навіть повною мірою надійним джерелом, але вона часто надає непоганий огляд сторонніх джерел (зокрема [і на Ваші роботи вона теж посилається, принаймні англійська](//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?oldid=1000870671#Notes)). Щодо посилань, то намагайтеся, будь ласка, красиво оформлювати їх відразу (незручні редиректи типу oke.io недоречні).

Comment: Про всяк зауважу про ненаукову саморекламу Вакуленка.

Answer (score -2):

[image] гуманітарка пообіцяла про це колись поговорити, а поки тільки сказали, що ну звуку г-ґ після н в англійській точно нема))0

Comment: По-моєму, доречним ще буде оце відео — https://youtu.be/fJCqNgqLlSg?t=130 — тут Остап вимовляє [ɣ] і [ɦ].